# Getting the desired data from list

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

```
data SomeData = A Int
              | B Int
              | C Int

list :: [SomeData]
list = [ A 1, B 2, C 3]

wantedData = filter (?) list -- wantedData is A 1
```

For the code above, what function should I put in (?) so that I get the desired data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the list to contain `A` values then this should work as your predicate:

```
isA (A _) = True
isA _ = False
```

It's just pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

Something closer to the ability to write an anonymous function, and not having to define a new function, is a list comprehension.

For example, you can say

```
list = [ A 1, B 2, C 3]

wantedData = [ A n | A n <- list ] -- result: [A 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
data SomeData = A Int | B Int | C Int
                            deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

list :: [SomeData]
list = [ A 1, B 2, C 3 ]

wantedData :: [SomeData]
wantedData = filter (== A 1) list             -- wantedData is A 1
```

Test:

```
> wantedData 
> [A 1]
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted a function that got all data that was tagged with `A`

Comment: @amindfv: ah, ok, you are right. In order to get all data that was tagged with an A your list comprehension solution is better. ;)